# Passing Image through hook

Tags: 8, theming, hooks, media, paragraphs

## Background:

Im working in Drupal 8 and I have a paragraph type that contains a title and an image and I am trying to pass it through the preprocessor hook so I can set it inside a html template. For testing purposes all I have on my template is div that calls the image variable. Im more worried about the pre_processor than I am the html

## Code:

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->getType() == 'landing_page') {
    $paragraphs = $variables['node']->field_section->getValue();
    $section = [];
    foreach ($paragraphs as $key => $paragraph) {
      $p = Paragraph::load($paragraph['target_id']);

      echo "<pre>".print_r($p,TRUE)."</pre>";

      switch ($p->getType()) {
        case 'tabbed_body':
          foreach ($p->field_body_tab_content->getValue() as $tab) {
            $t = Paragraph::load($tab['target_id']);
            $title = $t->field_body_tab_title->getValue();
            $content = $t->field_tab_content->getValue();
            $image = $t->field_body_image->getValue();
            $section[$key]['tabbed_body'][] = [
              'title' => $title[0]['value'],
              'content' => $content[0]['value'],
              'image' => $image[0],
            ];
          }
          break;    
      }
    }
    $variables['sections'] = $section;
   }
}
```

Image Settings:
[image: Tab_Image Display Settings]

Comment: This might not be the best approach, see the discussions in this threads https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269468/what-is-the-difference-between-getvalue-and-referencedentities-to-fetch-para

Comment: @4k4 I just want the users to be able to provide the images, and text then from there use preprocessor hook to get it to the template so I can format it the way I want. There can be one picture per tab. 

Is it really that hard to do it that way?

Comment: @4k4 are you saying on the template file I should just do <img src = "{{ content.field_body_image }}"></img>?

Comment: `{{ content.field_body_image }}` should render to an `<img ...` tag automatically, based on your field display setting.

Comment: @Kevin I see no option for field display setting on the page, would you like to see screenshots of what I do see?

Currently I am in the following breadcrumb path `Home->Administration->structure->paragraph types->Body tab->Body Tab`  I am currently looking at the edit tab_image settings for Body Tab

Comment: They’re just fields regardless of if it’s in a Paragraph or Node type... they will have display settings on them.

Comment: @Kevin Can you look at the picture I attached to my original post then and tell me what to change from there to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass only the image `uri`, and render image using it in the twig.
Try the following suggestion:
In your loop try to get image as the following:

```
  $image_field_values= $t->field_body_image->getValue();
  /**
   * @TODO: if you have multiple values loop through them i will test just by the first
   */
  $image_target_id = $image_field_values[0]['target_id'];
  $image_file = File::load($image_target_id);
  $section[$key]= [
    'image_uri' => $image_file->getFileUri()
  ];
```

In your twig will be something like:

```
<img src="{{ file_url(section[0]['image_uri'])}}" >
```

Don't forget `use Drupal\file\Entity\File;`.

Comment: This works!! Sorry I wasted my bounty on another question so I dont have enough rep to upvote you

Comment: it's okay, i'm glad that help you. market it as the accepted answer in case someone needs it.