# Paragraph's fields value loaded in a custom controller are in the default language instead of the current language

Tags: 8, entities, i18n-l10n, paragraphs

I made a custom controller that load a paragraph field from a node and then render some part in a template. The paragraph field field_title and field_description are translatable.

The translation works fine on the admin side. I followed https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/paragraphs/multilingual-paragraphs-configuration and I can see the content is translated from the admin. But my controller only loads the default language value instead of the current language.

```php
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\MyModule\Controller\MyModuleController.
 */

namespace Drupal\MyModule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class MyModuleController extends ControllerBase {
    
    /**
     * Controller load the game
     * 
     * @return \Drupal\MyModule\Controller\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function gameView() {
        
        $nid = 1;
        
        // Load the game
        $game = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);
                
        $stages = [];
        
        // Get all the stages of the game
        $paragraph_field_items = $game->get('field_stages')->getValue();
        if (!$paragraph_field_items) {
            throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException('This game has no level');
        }
            
        // Get storage for paragraph
        $paragraph_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('paragraph');
        // Collect paragraph field's ids.
        $ids = array_column($paragraph_field_items, 'target_id');
        // Load all paragraph objects.
        $paragraphs_objects = $paragraph_storage->loadMultiple($ids);

        /** @var \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph $paragraph */
        foreach ($paragraphs_objects as $paragraph) {
          // Get field from the paragraph.

          $description = [
              '#type' => 'processed_text',
              '#text' => $paragraph->get('field_description')->value,
              '#format' => 'basic_html',
          ];

          $stages [] = [
              'title' => $paragraph->get('field_title')->value,
              'image' => $paragraph->get('field_image'),
              'description' => $description,
              'east_lv95' => $paragraph->get('field_east_lv95')->value,
              'north_lv95' => $paragraph->get('field_north_lv95')->value,
          ];
        }
        
                  
        return [
            '#theme' => 'game_map',
            '#party' => $party,
            '#stages' => $stages,
            '#game' => $game,
        ];
    }
```

Comment: This might be helpful https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269468/what-is-the-difference-between-getvalue-and-referencedentities-to-fetch-para

Comment: After you loaded the `$game` with the entity type manager, load the translation with the entity repository: `$game = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($game);`. So you just have to add this one line to the code you already have. And maybe consider injecting the services instead, since `\Drupal` calls should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments I changed `$game->get('field_stages')->getValue();` for `$game->get('field_stages')->referencedEntities();`. This allow me to greatly simply a part of the code.

To load the correct language I added `$paragraph = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($paragraph);` inside the loop. Using getTranslationFromContext on the $game didn't works for the paragraph.

I'm not 100% satisfied as I feel translation should be loaded directly when all the fields are loaded with referencedEntities(). But it works and perhaps caching do some magic behind the scene.

This answer helped a lot https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/269493/1761

```php
// Load the game
$game = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($gameID);

$stages = [];

// Get all the stage of the game
$paragraph_field_items = $game->get('field_stages')->referencedEntities();

if (!$paragraph_field_items) {
    throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException('This game has no level');
}
    
/** @var \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph $paragraph */
foreach ($paragraph_field_items as $paragraph) {

  // Get the translation
  $paragraph = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($paragraph);
    
  $description = [
      '#type' => 'processed_text',
      '#text' => $paragraph->get('field_description')->value,
      '#format' => 'basic_html',
  ];

  $stages [] = [
      'title' => $paragraph->get('field_title')->value,
      'image' => $paragraph->get('field_image'),
      'description' => $description,
      'east_lv95' => $paragraph->get('field_east_lv95')->value,
      'north_lv95' => $paragraph->get('field_north_lv95')->value,
  ];
}
```